# SignalR .NET client not firing events when network connection is lost

Tags: asp.net, wpf, signalr, signalr.client

I have WPF application that connects to WebAPI, which runs SignalR. Everything works fine, until Internet connection is lost by client. 
When it happens, SignalR does not fire any events on client side (StateChanged, Error, Reconnecting, Closed etc.)

Code is pretty straightforward

```
 public HubConnection _hubConnection;
 IHubProxy _proxy;
 public async Task ConnectToHub(string hubUrl, string hubName)
 {
      _hubConnection = new HubConnection(HubURL);
      _hubConnection.Reconnecting += hubConnection_Reconnecting; 
      _hubConnection.Closed += _hubConnection_Closed;
      _hubConnection.StateChanged += _hubConnection_StateChanged;
      proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(hubName);

      await _hubConnection.Start();  

 }


   void _hubConnection_StateChanged(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.StateChange obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void _hubConnection_Closed()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    void _hubConnection_Reconnectig()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

SignalR version 2.2.0
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transport type on SignalR was set automatically to **ServerSentEvents** instead of **WebSockets** (Server admin didn't turn it on). Turned out that **only** with Websockets we can get connection-related events on .Net-client, when connection is lost.

According to http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

> WebSocket is the only transport that establishes a true persistent, two-way connection between client and server.

Answer (score 3):

Try subscribing to the Error event. Depending on "how" the connection is lost, I don't think some of the other events will get fired.

```
 _hubConnection.Error += (e=>{ ... });
```

Comment: Another thing that's caught me out on occasion is hosting a SignalR server within an MVC app, stopping the debugger and forgetting that ISS keeps it running in the background. Always check the IIS express tray icon to make sure your web app has in fact shut down.